# Blob Objects sent through Axios are empty in Express

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I'm sending a Blob Object created in VueJS to ExpressJS via Axios.post.

But if I send the BlobObject itself via Axiox, I can check it in req.body, but if I send it from ExpressJS to an object that wraps the Blob Object via Axios in order to get it in the form of `const {blob} = req.body`, ExpresJS BlobObject is empty.

How can I solve this?

**Blob Object in Vue Component**

```
Blob {size: 42003, type: ""}
size: 42003
type: ""
__proto__: Blob
```

**Send Blob Object (Axios & Express) 1**

```
// Vue Component
axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/blob`, this.blobObject)
    .then(
         (response) => {
              console.log('Successfully Save API')
         },
         (err) => {
              console.error(err)
         }
    )

// Express Router

router.post('/blob', (req, res, next) => {
...
console.log(req.body)
})

// req.body
{  "PK\u0003\u0004\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000'\u0015\u001aO����%\u0003\u0000\u0000�\u0006\u0000\u0000\f\u0000\u0000\u0000project.json�TA��D\u0014�+�pٕR��3\u001e��\u0001�\u0015\u0005�\u00
16$vEAU%�3ϩ��Ɠ4�\u0012\t!\u000e��\u0004h/{�8U�\u0001�������a�R5T�K���{o�����8iG�:2|pB����\u0011���S\u0018�V6h�ul@f�V��\u0001sO�ǟ�9~�Z": 'x�����l���F�\b6I؏�~�:;\r��l��)\u0019Ї�\u0001���\u001fv�fa��J^��Q�K[��
�v�EM�E��tn�!Q���kܲ����\u0011��q�D\\ӄE�.�"�cʁ�J@g\\���:�쏟~\u000f"�4:���\u0017�a7\u001ba��N�6���f\u001d��IW��\u0010a���\fcN�G?"�(�ˇ\u0003ҙi��CϘ��,�\\\u0015�dE*X\\p�K(ʔ3�^A����:��r��r�zD�a.�(E �l','5\u001c��5�b�5��sC�ۣ���g?�\u001dk�\u0000���`��p�L\f\u0019\n4g�\u0006sle�M$ޚZ�a�\t��<*bZ�k���\u001cM\u0000ԣ��\u001dM{�Ӻ^\u000e��Xʺ�\u0012����\u0017�|q~�|u����_���\u0016��/�"�\u0012V': 
'',
....
....
}
```

**Send Blob Object (Axios & Express) 2**

```
// Vue Component
axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/blob`, { "blob": this.blobObject })
    .then(
         (response) => {
              console.log('Successfully Save API')
         },
         (err) => {
              console.error(err)
         }
    )

// Express Router

router.post('/blob', (req, res, next) => {
...
console.log(req.body)
})

// req.body
"blob": {} // blobObject is Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

add HTTP headers with Axios request

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/blob`,
{ "blob": this.blobObject },
{ 
 headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
})
.then(
     (response) => {
          console.log('Successfully Save API')
     },
     (err) => {
          console.error(err)
     }
)
```

and make sure you have JSON parser middleware eg (if an app is your express app)

```
app.use(express.json());
```